# Hierarchical Indentation

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Not sure of the best way to describe it but a picture should work.  I have data structured as a tree and I'd like to display it with various levels of indentation.

```
[1                        ]
    [1a                   ]
        [1ai              ]
    [1b                   ]
[2                        ]
[3                        ]
    [3a                   ]
```

etc

The key being indenting the left and lining up on the right.

Programatically increasing the padding-left of each element works for the first half, but might not be the correct approach.

I'm using a recursive angular component, though I didn't mention angular originally b/c i don't think its necessarily relevant to the solution.

ts

```
export class HierarchicalJobNodeComponent{

  @Input() job: JobHierarchical;

  @Input() depth: number;


  pxDepth(): string {
    return this.depth + "px";
  }

  style(): Object {
    return  { 'margin-left': this.depth + "px", 'width':'100%' };
  }
}
```

html

```
<div class="node container" [ngStyle]="style()">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">{{job.job_JobId}}</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">{{job.job_Status}}</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">{{job.jobDefinition_SearchName}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child row">
    <div *ngFor="let child of job.childJobs">
      <hjobnode [depth]="depth+20" [job]="child"></hjobnode>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
  style(): Object {
    return  { 'padding-left': this.depth + "px", 'width':'100%' };
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And you just want to solve this with HTML and CSS? (which is doable)

Comment: Basically just described the purpose of like the `ul` & `ol` elements.

Comment: @lumio I updated the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach using padding was the right way to go. The easiest would be to nest those items within one another, so you don't need to think about the depth.

As Chris W. pointed out, this can be easily represented as a list, using `ul` (or `ol`) and `li`s.

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li>ul {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 2.1</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>Item 2.1.1</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    Item 3
    <!-- you can even nest the ul directly inside an item !-->
    <ul>
      <li>Item 3.1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope that helped

Comment: Turned out to get the visual I wanted I just had to put the style on the first "row" class element, instead of the container one.  That said, we'll see how it goes once I add more content, maybe I'll end up restructuring like you suggested.

Thanks!